# Rigged model deforms horribly when doing anything in edit mode

Tags: modeling, mesh, rigging

I'm following this tutorial that models a puppy.

After modeling the puppy in the tutorial it's shown how to add a meta-rig. I set up all the bones then realized I needed to do some more modeling.

When I try to do this in Edit mode it goes ballistic and explodes in all directions. I have read something on this forum that sounds somewhere close to this problem. The suggestion is that you can click the "remove rigid body tools" button under physics in the tool side panel. I did that, but it didn't work.

I even went as far as to delete the entire rig to see if that would work but that didn't work either. Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have learned that if you have shape keys and one of the shape keys is selected other than the basis, it will do as I described in this post. If you simply click the basis on your shape keys panel and you will be able to edit your mesh/model at will.